# Maintaining session while executing shell commands using a java program

Tags: java

We are working on a requirement to execute shell commands from java swing UI.

We need to execute one command to start the session, once the session is started we need to execute some common commands repeatedly.

We are able to execute the commands using the below command.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("setSession")
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("execute individual task");
```

this way, everytime we have to set the session and executing the individual tasks.

Is there any way to execute a command (like setSession) once and retain the session to execute the remaining commands?

Comment: Why not group together all the individual tasks under one shell scripts, and launch just that one?

Comment: We can do that, but it have to execute from the beginning for every task. I wanted to keep the setSession common for all the individual tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If I got Your task right, You might want to start a shell on the underlying system, get it's input and output streams and issue Your commands there.
Though that makes You operation system dependent. But commands You executing probably are anyway.
Something like:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");
OutputStream outputStream = p.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));

InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

writer.write("dir \n");
writer.flush();
```